# ZoomPanView extends View casting error

Tags: java, android

People!

I write a class like so:

```
public class ZoomPanView extends ImageView { ... }
```

then in the Activity I put:

```
View        vb1 = findViewById(R.id.BodyPicture);        /* ok */
ImageView   vb2 = (ImageView) vb1;                  /* ok */
ZoomPanView vb3 = (ZoomPanView) vb2;          /* ClassCast exception */
```

and it crashes at the Cast.  I *assumed* by extending ImageView to ZoomPanView I could do the cast.  So I assumed wrong.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you have to use

Like this way
in your .XML file write

```
<yourpackagenameclassname.ZoomPanView 
android:id="@+id/BodyPicture"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
</ZoomPanView>
```

In your class access this ZoomPanView

```
ZoomPanView vb3 = (ZoomPanView)findViewById(R.id.BodyPicture);
```

Comment: @GopalRao  thanks both for your assistance!  I had no idea that I could specify the class of the widget in the XML file, although now I realize I've been doing that all along... 

no run time crash -- back to fixing pan and zoom logic

Answer (score 0):

is your `ImageZoomView` class subclass of `ZoomPanView`? if not,

change

```
 ZoomPanView vb3 = (ImageZoomView) vb2;
```

to

```
 ZoomPanView vb3 = (ZoomPanView) vb2;
```

Comment: replaced the code with what was really there (the new class is called ZoomPanView)